# O que significa offset no pillow?

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens

O método [`getoffset()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html?highlight=getoffset#PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.getoffset) da classe `PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont` retorna uma tupla. O que são essas medidas exatamente?

Utilizo o **Pillow** na versão **6.1.0**.

Comment: Que versão do Pillow você se refere?

Comment: Chegou a ver na [documentação](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html?highlight=getoffset#PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.getoffset)?

Comment: @fernandosavio Isso não é da classe `PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont`?

Comment: Yep, essa documentação me deixou mais confuso que surdo em bingo...
Ignora meu comentário anterior..

Comment: Olha não conheço, pillow, mas para mim tais valores dizem respeito as coordenadas x,y no plano cartesiano do objeto em questão.

Comment: Sim, recorri ao fórum pq também achei a documentação bem confusa. Me refiro à versão 6.1.0.

Comment: Anderson, sim a classe é PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont. Obrigado pela correção, irei editar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"offset" significa "deslocamento" - 
O método `.getoffset` de objetos do tipo "Font" dentro do módulo `ImageFont` requer uma string de texto - e devolve a posição, em pixels, a partir da qual ele começaria a desenhar texto se aquele texto fosse ser desenhando em uma imagem.

Para quase todas as strings o retorno é "0, 0" - se você não está criando um programa para typesetting, e usando caracteres especiais bem estranhos, não vai encontrar nenhum caso em que o retorno do `.getoffset` vai ser diferente de 0,0 - 
e, de qualquer forma, ele é desenhado para ser usado internamente pelas funções que de fato vão desenhar o texto nas imagens (usando, em geral, o método `text` de um objeto `ImageDraw.Draw` - você passa a fonte como parâmetro pra ele, e, o uso interno desse método é que vai usar  `.getoffset`, `.getmask`, etc... na fonte).

Resumindo:

- o valor é o deslocamento em pixels onde o desenho de uma fonte vai começar
- o valor retornado vai ser quase sempre (0, 0)
- você não precisa chamar esse método diretamente

Comment: Muito obrigado, jsbueno!